# How to Link Google Drive, Dropbox, or other Folders Into Encrypted Home Folders?

Tags: mount, fstab, ecryptfs, symbolic-link

## Question

How can I mount these folders only after I've logged into the user with the encrypted home folder?

## System

What I am trying to do is bind:
`/home/username/Dropbox/Documents` to `/home/username/Documents` on startup.

On another computer running Ubuntu 12.04 I did this by placing the following line in `/etc/fstab`:

```
/home/username/Dropbox/Documents /home/username/Documents auto bind
```

## Issue

However, on this computer, I have an encrypted home folder, so `fstab` claims that the location does not exist on boot, asking me to skip mounting it or manually repair.

## Similar To

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/676502/how-to-fuse-mount-into-home-folders-after-ecryptfs-is-mounted ; (Is asking specifically about mounting, using fuse, and after the ecryptfs home folder has been mounted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option that might be of interest for you, would be symlinking it:

```
ln -s /home/username/Dropbox/Documents /home/username/Documents
```

Comment: I hadn't thought about this, is there a way to give the symlink the original Documents folder icon so you can't tell it's a symlink?   Edit: I realized I didn't have to delete the folder first and can directly link to the folder still a bit new to ubuntu. lol